# GCC compiler: error linker command failed using the Make file

Tags: c, gcc, linker-errors

I have the following C file and I am using the Mac OS X GCC compiler.

You find the error below.

```
#include "support.h"

#ifdef _WIN32

#include <conio.h>

void support_init() {
    // Not needed
}

void support_clear() {
    system("CLS");
}

int support_readkey(int timeout_ms) {
    Sleep(timeout_ms);
    if (!kbhit()) return 0;
    return getch();
}

#else

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

void support_init() {
    struct termios tio;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &tio);
    tio.c_lflag &= (~ICANON & ~ECHO);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tio);
}

void support_clear() {
    printf("\x1B[2J\x1B[0;0f");
}

int support_readkey(int timeout_ms) {
    struct timeval tv = { 0L, timeout_ms * 1000L };
    fd_set fds;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(0, &fds);
    int r = select(1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    if (!r) return 0;

    return getchar();
}

#endif
```

And this is my Makefile:

```
CFLAGS=-std=c11 -Wall -g
CC=clang

all: snake

.PHONY: all clean

snake: snake.o support.o

snake.o: snake.c support.h

clean:
    rm -f snake
    rm -f snake.o support.o
```

When I try to compile with the command "make all" I get the following error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
invocation)
```

Comment: You are using `clang`, not `gcc`.  The Makefile explicitly specifies it, and the error message clearly indicates it.  If you want good help then do get your story (and tags) straight.

Comment: Though the error message is a bit unclear, it could well be caused by the absence of a `main()` function in `snake.c`.  The `main()` function is your program's entry point; every program must have exactly one, defined somewhere among its source files.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your help

Comment: the snake.c file has an empty main-function
Do I have to type "gcc" instead of "clang" in the Makefile?

Answer (score -1):

Check the architecture. Based on that, the *CFLAGS* should be updated to set to `-m32` or `-m64`.

For successful compilation on a 64-bit machine, this has to be set to `-m64`:

```
CFLAGS+= -m64
```